# Stream is not called in android

Tags: java, android, java-stream

I have stream:

```
Stream.of(coachingAreas)
            .map(coachingArea -> Observable.from(coachingArea.weeks)
            .map(coachingWeekRef -> coachingMap.put(coachingWeekRef.id, coachingWeekRef.version)));
```

every array has data and is not empty, but this line: `coachingMap.put(coachingWeekRef.id, coachingWeekRef.version)`
is not called. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You haven't performed a terminal operation on the
   stream for that reason the stream remains idle. intermediate operations are driven by terminal operations. Essentially terminal operations produce a *non-stream* result such as a primitive value, an object, a collection etc.
2. don't do `coachingMap.put` within the `map` intermediate operation as  you're introducing a side-effect, rather use the `toMap` collector.

Assuming both `coachingWeekRef.id` and `coachingWeekRef.version` are integers then the whole query would look like this:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> resultSet = 
     Stream.of(coachingAreas)
           .map(coachingArea -> Observable.from(coachingArea.weeks))
           .collect(Collectors.toMap(ClassName::getId, ClassName::getVersion));
```

or use a lambda expression to extract the map key and value rather than a method reference if you prefer.